# Is my quanteda dictionary detecting terms in texts that are not contained in the dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, text-classification, quanteda

(First time asking a question; new-ish to R and new to quanteda).

I have about 1.5m tweets and I have created a dictionary of about 1,700 abusive terms in an Excel file. I would like to use the quanteda dictionary to classify as abusive all those tweets which contain any of the abusive terms in the dictionary. The dictionary contains multi-word expressions. When I run the code below (on a random sample of 100 tweets), tweets that do not contain terms from the dictionary are classified as abusive, but I'm not sure why. I wondered if it has to do with the multi-word expressions in the dictionary. For example, if one of the multi-word expressions in the dictionary contains the word "the", is the dictionary classifying all tweets that contain the word "the" as abusive?

```
# Load the dictionary from Excel
abuse_words <- data.frame(read_excel("Final Dictionary - All Abuse Terms.xlsx"))

# Create corpus of tweets from data.frame object called Random100
tweets_corpus <- corpus(Random100, text_field = "tweet")

# Create quanteda dictionary object
dictionary <- dictionary(list(Abusive = abuse_words$Term)

# Apply the dictionary
tweets_dfm <- dfm(tweets_corpus, dictionary = dictionary)
```

Comment: We would need to be able to see what you are picking up first in the `abuse_words` and in your `dictionary` object, before your question can be answered. What are you getting as a result, and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: @KenBenoit I think (?!) I've solved it. I think it was simply a case of setting valuetype = "fixed". Looking through the results now, it appears that the dictionary is only picking out tweets that contain exact words/phrases from the dictionary